Calling methods from array of method pointers not executing
This doesn't execute any suggestions:
void (CClient::*pMethod[CNetwork::ClientEvent::E_CE_MAX_EVENTS])();

pMethod[CNetwork::ClientEvent::E_CE_ACCEPTED] = &CClient::Accepted;
pMethod[CNetwork::ClientEvent::E_CE_ACCOUNT_INFO] = &CClient::AccountInfo;

// This code does nothing
CClient::pMethod[m_network->m_type];


You need to use () to call a function/method.

Side note: that initial array definition could be much clearer with an appropriate typedef: typedef void (CClient::*ptr)(); ptr my_array[CNetwork::ClientEvent::E_CE_MAX_EVENTS];.

C++ expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type.  I get that error when putting parenthesis at the end.

I Forgot to mention I am calling the array of methods from inside the class.

@developer68 -- your question was closed as a duplicate. Is there something here that the duplicate doesn't address?

Yes how to call the method from inside the class that the array is defined in.  Would you at least share the thread that this is a duplicate of?

Your code is merely retrieving a pointer from the array, but it is not actually calling a method via the pointer. Also, you need an object to call the method on, eg: CClient client; (client.*pMethod[m_network->m_type])(); Or, if you are inside another method of CClient, just use this->* instead, eg: (this->*pMethod[m_network->m_type])();

@developer68 You should see the duplicate in big blue box (in dark mode, not sure how light looks like) on top of this page, right below title of your question. Alternatively, all links that were in comments (including duplicate questions) are on the right, below yellow box "Hot on Meta" in "Linked" section.

Remy Thank You.  (this->*pMethod[m_network->m_type])();
